# python pyautogui AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'size'

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributeerror, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui
import time

def pause():
    time.sleep(0.001)

while True:
    pyautogui.keyDown('down')


    time.sleep(5)
```

Gives me error

```
C:\Python27\python.exe E:/Python/win32/pythongui.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python/win32/pythongui.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "E:\Python\win32\pyautogui.py", line 45, in <module>
    screenWidth, screenHeight = pyautogui.size()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'size'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I don't understand why I get this error I don't even call attribute size and yesterday everything worked just fine. Today for some weird reason I keep getting this error. Code is exactly same as before when pyautogui worked.

Comment: Any chance you have a file called `pyautogui.py` in the current working directory? Rename that (and delete a possibly existing `pyautogui.pyc` file).

Comment: Yup there was pyautogui.pyc file for some reason. Because name was so similiar to pythongui I didn't notice. Thank you for help. Question can be closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beacuse you  set the file name to pyautogui.py, which apparently conflicts with the package you importing.
change your file name and run again 
Refer this issue:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/1588